How to access session data in server-side component?
In Next.js, within layout.js, I have a  component. The Menu component is server-side. In this menu, I load menu items for normal users. Then, I have  specifically for admins. In AdminMenu, I must determine if the current user's email is admin@gmail.com. If it is, then they are an admin; otherwise, they are not. The problem is that AdminMenu must be available for SEO and should be server-side. How can I achieve this?
export const Menu = () => {

    const items = menuItems.getUserItems();


    return (
        <div className={styles.menu}>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <Link key={index} className={styles.menuItem} href={item.link}>{item.label}</Link>
            ))}
            <AdminMenu></AdminMenu>
        </div>
    )
}


export const AdminMenu = () => {

    const { data } = useSession();

    console.log('data', data);

    const isAdmin = data.user.email == 'admin@gmail.com';

    return (
        (isAdmin && <div>admin menu item</div>)

    )
}

